# Using scalatest + robolectric

Tags: android, scala, robolectric, scalatest

I'm trying to write tests for an android lib using scalatest + robolectric but I couldn't find any piece of documentation around this. Also, I would like to be able to run my test suite through the scalatest ant task. Has anyone done this before or know some way out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat late, but by now this can be done relatively easy with [RoboTest](https://github.com/zbsz/robotest).

Some [brief documentation](http://scala-on-android.taig.io/testing/robolectric/) and also a [sample project](https://github.com/Taig/Hello-Scala).